# Javascript ES6 spread transformation changing Promise return content in Nest JS auth example

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nest

I'm using some of the NestJS sample repo [19-auth-jwt](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/19-auth-jwt) to implement an authentication system. But I'm facing a bug.

In the provider for the auth module (auth.services.ts), the method `validateUser()` uses JS ES6 syntax to remove the password from the user before returning it, as explained in [the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-passport-strategies).

```
  async validateUser(username: string, pass: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOne(username);
    if (user && user.password === pass) {
      const { password, ...result } = user;
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

This is not working for me, `result` looks like this:

```
{
  '$__': InternalCache {
    activePaths: StateMachine {
      paths: [Object],
      states: [Object],
      stateNames: [Array]
    },
    skipId: true,
    strictMode: true,
    selected: {},
    fields: {},
    exclude: null
  },
  '$isNew': false,
  _doc: {
    _id: new ObjectId("6299077a1c8989d6bdc3cb34"),
    first_name: 'Test',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '$2b$10$/ndkmG7qLh8RReko7TvsPOC15xd.mVDUY9mC3SVbkVndgZlVDzU4.',
    __v: 0
  }
}
```

Not only has it not removed the password but also it is creating a bizarre data structure which means I can't get the user data which I then need to pass in my JWT without changing the code to access the `_doc`.

If I just return `user` instead it works (but obviously doesn't remove the password).

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening? My best guess is this is something to do with promises but don't know.
2. Should I be concerned about not removing the password if it is well protected? Note that I'm not actually returning it, this request only returns the JWT which holds the user _id, no more data.
3. If it is a concern, what can I do about it?
4. Is this a bug or my mistake?

I'm using MongoDB and mongoose as you might be able to tell. I'm new to Nest btw.

[Reference to the code line where this is happening](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/f3b866262048e236d816d70e3cf3084146c30614/sample/19-auth-jwt/src/auth/auth.service.ts#L15).

Thank you!

EDIT:

The findOne method in the user provider looks like this; a simple mongoose query.

```
async findOneByEmail(email: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return await this.userModel.findOne({ email: email }).exec();
  }
```

Comment: The thing is that since you are using mongoose/mongodb you are not getting back a simple object with the data you want, but a Mongoose document. Can you post what you do in your `usersService.findOne` method ?

Comment: Yeah but the thing that weirds me out is removing the {password, ...result} line fixes it. The findOne method is simple, I've added it to the question.

Comment: Try with using `.lean()` instead of `.exec()` (*if it is only for reading*).

Comment: Spot on! Fixed it, thank you so much.